# how to add tomcat self signed cert to RHEL 7 trust store?

Tags: linux, ssl, redhat, tomcat, https

This is my first time using linux and even tomcat. Im trying to use https since i have a script to run that will take my https url but it prompts me a warning as it is a self signed cert.I would not like to see this warning.

I come from a Windows platform and apparently in windows i can add the cert into the truststore and windows will automatically trust this.

How do i do it in rhel? as i have generated it using the keytool and successfully created the keystore. but what file should i import?

Could someone guide me or point me to the right place? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the selfsigned root in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` and run `update-ca-trust` as root

Comment: the selfsigned is in a keystore. what should i put into that directory? the keystore

Comment: Extract it as a pem.